# understand perfetto Uninterruptible Sleep

Tags: android, perfetto

I have one perfetto trace, which include a app anr. when open the trace in perfetto, I found that ANR process actuall in "Uninterruptible Sleep" for almost 40 secs.

How to understand what happened for this app?
[image]

Comment: you should upload your perfetto trace.

It's very easy to find out.

Just click the sched event above your thread, and look the panel at bottom of  the window.

https://perfetto.dev/docs/data-sources/cpu-scheduling

Comment: Uninterruptible Sleep usually caused by I/O,   sometime it's caused by  I/O trashing because of low memory.

Only by looking your perfetto trace can figure it out.

Comment: exactly, I saw it marked as "uninterruptible sleep(IO)", so it means it's waiting IO. any suggestion how to identify what's the issue from IO (maybe diskIO)?

Comment: use need capture ftrace to track down.

Comment: usually caused by file reading or kswapd which swaps memory out